# Debug groovy script within a container

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy

I'm building a jenkins container and want to set the KeycloakSecurityRealm in the initial flow. I already have a script which works fine for default settings:

```
    import hudson.*
    import hudson.model.*
    import jenkins.*
    import jenkins.model.*
    import java.util.logging.Logger
    import hudson.security.*
    import java.util.*
    import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.*
    import java.lang.reflect.*

    import org.jenkinsci.plugins

    /*
    NOTE:  that megascript should be split someday, when my groovy skills improves.
    */

    Thread.start {
        //vbles definition
        def logger = Logger.getLogger("")
        def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
        def pm = instance.getPluginManager()
        def uc = instance.getUpdateCenter()
        def installed = false
    // More code...

    //No plugins to update. Security can be set
        logger.info("All plugins are up to date")
        logger.info("Setting security")

        //  logger.info("Creating initial user")
        //  hudsonRealm.createAccount("USER","USER")

        logger.info("Creating reaml")
        def keycloakSecurityRealm = keycloakRealm.createSecurityComponents()

        //realm based on jenkins database
        logger.info("Setting Security realm to KEYCLOAK")
        instance.setSecurityRealm(keycloakSecurityRealm)

        //not anonymous read allowed
```

This code crashes without any information. I whould like to debug the container so I've checked I can run the step where the container crashes to attach an interactive console:

[image]

Can do

```
docker run -ti 3ed
```

And I have access to the container as root.

Problem is I can't debug the script. I've checked there are some ways as using [jdb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) but in all cases it is neccessary a mail java class for running it. The original script worked when called without changes so it runs file without any classes.

How could I debug this kind of java scripts inside a container?

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not tag your question with [tag:java] when your question is about [tag:groovy].  You attract the wrong experts by doing this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once inside container, make sure to run your code in debug mode.

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=32887 ...
```

In case you have no chance to start java by yourself, you can always use `_JAVA_OPTIONS`

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=32887
```

Attach your debugger (e.g. IntelliJ) to remote machine (your Docker based container). Debug the code from the IDE started outside the container.

It should do the trick.

For a sample (used for profiling) take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/ProfilerDocker

It's not the same thing, but it's similar in a sense that Docker based code (Java) is executed inside container, while profiler (running outside container) is attached to remote machine.